# Generate video that will play on Android and iOS

Tags: android, bash, cordova, video, codec

I'm building a Phonegap app with Django that converts an album of images into a video by calling the following commands in turn from the shell:

```
mogrify -resize 640x480 *.jpg
convert *.jpg -delay 10 -morph 10 %05d.morph.jpg
avconv -f image2 -i %05d.morph.jpg -r 7600 -s 800x600 video.mp4 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The resulting video plays on iOS, but not on Android - it just won't start. I'm guessing that I'm not passing through the right options to `avconv` to use the right codec, but I'm not sure what the correct options are. Can anyone enlighten me as to what options I can pass through to get a video that will play on iOS and Android?

The server OS is Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For choosing the right codec, you can refer to the Android [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) page for an idea of what formats and codecs you can expect to play on which versions of Android.  Of all of those listed, H.264 AVC is presently the best option due to backwards compatibility back to Android 3.0 and wide support among other platforms, [including iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) and just about every desktop browser.

As for generating the file, the [Libav wiki](https://wiki.libav.org/Encoding/h264) suggests -c:v libx264 or -c:v h264 should work interchangeably if you have the codecs installed, so in order to generate a file with the right codec, I'd modify your avconv line like so:

`avconv -f image2 -i %05d.morph.jpg -r 7600 -s 800x600 -c:v h264 video.mp4 >/dev/null 2>&1`

Hopefully, that will give you a file that plays everywhere you need it to.

Good luck!